# How can I ovveride tabs css styles in component.css by using customClass?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I use `ngx-bootstrap/tabs`for tabs.

Here is my HTML-Template:

```
<tabset [justified]="true">
  <tab heading="About" customClass="about-tab">
    <app-about></app-about>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Projects" customClass="projects-tab">
    <app-projects></app-projects>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

With my custom css classes I would override default tab styling. In my component.css I defined css rules, like this:

```
.about-tab {
  background-color: #c7c7c7;
  // more rules
}

.projects-tab {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  // more rules
}
```

But this doesn't work for me. Then I move my css rules in main styles.css of my angular app and it works, but this solution is not good for me, because I have one more component which also contain tabs.

Why it doesn't work from components.css? How can I bring to work my custom css styles from my component.css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/deep/`, `>>>`, and `::ng-deep` selectors will be deprecated in Angular at some point so I wouldn't rely on those. The only way I am aware is to set component `viewEncapsulation` to `none`, but be sure to wrap the styles to your component specifically so they won't leak since styles are added to global css scope.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-component.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Comment: :host and :host context it's not deprecated https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: I tried with ``ViewEncapsulation.None`` but this setting broke some styles an other place in the app

Comment: True that if we use ViewEncapsulation.None we must enclose all in a <div class="custom" and change .custom.about-tab, not only .about-tab

Comment: `:host` and `:host-context` are not deprecated indeed. But those cannot be used to escape out of component's style scope i.e. apply styles to child components.

Comment: However, I am not sure if `:host` could be used to css scope if viewEncapsulation is set to none. That would be a bit more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

use :host /deep/  in your component.css

```
:host /deep/ .about-tab {
  background-color: #c7c7c7;
  // more rules
}

:host /deep/ .projects-tab {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  // more rules
}
```